What is the relation between Vin, Vmid, and Vout in a cascading MOSFET amplifer?

It's problem 7.3 from Foundations of Analog and Digital.
I want to know the relation between vIN and vOUT. The amplifiers in problem 7.2 are also pasted as picture.

I saw some solutions (also pasted below) where it said that when vIN < vT, vMID will be vT, but I thought it should be vS. Moreover, I can't understand how the equation below pops out.


Without your added thoughts and some work, I won't address everything.
But I will help with this part:

Moreover I can't understand how the equation below pops out.

I tried to keep the steps very incremental in nature:
$$\require{cancel}
\begin{align*}
V_S&\le V_T-\frac1{KR}+\sqrt{\frac1{K^2R^2}+\frac{2V_S}{KR}}
\\\\
V_S-V_T+\frac1{KR}&\le \sqrt{\frac1{K^2R^2}+\frac{2V_S}{KR}}
\\\\
KR\left(V_S-V_T\right)+1&\le \sqrt{1+2KRV_S}
\\\\
K^2R^2\left(V_S^2 - 2V_SV_T + V_T^2\right) + \cancel{2KRV_S} - 2KRV_T +\cancel{1}&\le \cancel{1}+\cancel{2KRV_S}
\\\\
K^\cancel{2}R^\cancel{2}\left(V_S^2 - 2V_SV_T + V_T^2\right) &\le 2\cancel{KR}V_T
\\\\
KR &\le \frac{2V_T}{V_S^2 - 2V_SV_T + V_T^2}
\\\\
KR &\le \frac{2V_T}{\left(V_S - V_T\right)^2}
\end{align*}$$
Hopefully, the above process works for you. Just the usual deal of isolating the square-root on one side so that it can be readily squared. (So long as the left side isn't negative prior to squaring it.)
